# Codeigniter disable calendar date after 5 bookings

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have calendar whose dates are booked and saved in database. I am trying to pull the bookings from database and show then under corresponding date. Everything is working fine, except the thing, I want the date to be just text instead of link when there are more than 5 events to that date.

I am aware of the calendar template no content cell and content cells. But i want the date to have no link when it has more than 5 events attached to it.

My Model:

```
public function bookingcalender($year=null,$month=null)
    {
        if(!$year)
        {
            $y = date('Y');
        }
        else
        {
            $y = $year;
        }
        if(!$month)
        {
            $m = date('m');
        }
        else
        {
            $m = $month;
        }
        $this->config = array(
            'show_next_prev'  => TRUE,
            'next_prev_url'   => 'http://joshuaflinn.com/CI/booking/show',
            'template' => '{table_open}<table class="availability-calendar">{/table_open}          
            {heading_row_start}<tr class="toolbar">{/heading_row_start}        
            {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
            {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
            {heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}">&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}
            {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}
            {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
            {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
            {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}
            {cal_row_start}<tr>{/cal_row_start}
            {cal_cell_start}<td>{/cal_cell_start}
            {cal_cell_start_today}<td>{/cal_cell_start_today}
            {cal_cell_start_other}<td class="other-month">{/cal_cell_start_other}
            {cal_cell_content}<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bookingform" data="'.$y.'-'.$m.'-{day}">{day}</a><span class="date-data">{content}</span>{/cal_cell_content}
            {cal_cell_content_today}<div class="highlight"><a href="{content}">{day}</a></div>{/cal_cell_content_today}
            {cal_cell_no_content}<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bookingform" data="'.$y.'-'.$m.'-{day}">{day}</a>{/cal_cell_no_content}
            {cal_cell_no_content_today}<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bookingform"><div class="highlight">{day}</div></a>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}
            {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}
            {cal_cell_other}{day}{/cal_cel_other}
            {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
            {cal_cell_end_today}</td>{/cal_cell_end_today}
            {cal_cell_end_other}</td>{/cal_cell_end_other}
            {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}
            {table_close}</table>{/table_close}'
            );




        $this->load->library('calendar',$this->config);

        $conf_data = $this->get_booked_dates($year,$month);
        return $this->calendar->generate($year,$month,$conf_data);


    }  
    public function get_booked_dates($year,$month)
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('client_name,booking_date')->from('bookings')->like('booking_date',"$year-$month")->get();


        $cal_data = array();

        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $dt = explode("-", $row->booking_date);
            $dt = $dt[2];
            $k  = ($dt >= 10 ? substr($row->booking_date, 8,2) : substr($row->booking_date, 9,1));

            if( @$cal_data[$k] == '' )
            {
                $cal_data[$k] = $row->client_name;                
            }
            else
            {
                $cal_data[$k] .= ','.$row->client_name;                
            }

        }     

        return $cal_data;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The options you have are limited since Codeigniters Calendar Library only have the two pseudo variables `cal_cell_no_content` and `cal_cell_content`in the template to play with in terms of what content you want to display.

A quick look behind the door reveals that the library uses `isset()` to determine which of the two pseudo variables to use. 
And it calls str_replace `{content}` before `{day}` that opens up for a somewhat hacky solution:

```
public function bookingcalender($year=null,$month=null)
    {
        if(!$year)
        {
            $y = date('Y');
        }
        else
        {
            $y = $year;
        }
        if(!$month)
        {
            $m = date('m');
        }
        else
        {
            $m = $month;
        }
        $this->config = array(
            'show_next_prev'  => TRUE,
            'next_prev_url'   => 'http://joshuaflinn.com/CI/booking/show',
            'template' => '{table_open}<table class="availability-calendar">{/table_open}          
            {heading_row_start}<tr class="toolbar">{/heading_row_start}        
            {heading_title_cell}<th colspan="{colspan}">{heading}</th>{/heading_title_cell}
            {heading_previous_cell}<th><a href="{previous_url}">&lt;</a></th>{/heading_previous_cell}
            {heading_next_cell}<th><a href="{next_url}">&gt;</a></th>{/heading_next_cell}
            {heading_row_end}</tr>{/heading_row_end}
            {week_row_start}<tr>{/week_row_start}
            {week_day_cell}<td>{week_day}</td>{/week_day_cell}
            {week_row_end}</tr>{/week_row_end}
            {cal_row_start}<tr>{/cal_row_start}
            {cal_cell_start}<td>{/cal_cell_start}
            {cal_cell_start_today}<td>{/cal_cell_start_today}
            {cal_cell_start_other}<td class="other-month">{/cal_cell_start_other}
            {cal_cell_content}{content}{/cal_cell_content}
            {cal_cell_content_today}<div class="highlight">{content}</div>{/cal_cell_content_today}
            {cal_cell_no_content}<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bookingform" data="'.$y.'-'.$m.'-{day}">{day}</a>{/cal_cell_no_content}
            {cal_cell_no_content_today}<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bookingform"><div class="highlight">{day}</div></a>{/cal_cell_no_content_today}
            {cal_cell_blank}&nbsp;{/cal_cell_blank}
            {cal_cell_other}{day}{/cal_cel_other}
            {cal_cell_end}</td>{/cal_cell_end}
            {cal_cell_end_today}</td>{/cal_cell_end_today}
            {cal_cell_end_other}</td>{/cal_cell_end_other}
            {cal_row_end}</tr>{/cal_row_end}
            {table_close}</table>{/table_close}'
            );

        $this->load->library('calendar',$this->config);

        $conf_data = $this->get_booked_dates($year,$month);
        return $this->calendar->generate($year,$month,$conf_data);

    }  


    public function get_booked_dates($year,$month)
    {
        $query = $this->db->select('client_name,booking_date')->from('bookings')->like('booking_date',"$year-$month")->get();

        $cal_data = array();

        foreach($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $dt = explode("-", $row->booking_date);
            $k = intval($dt[2]); // MAKE INTEGER OF DAY NUMBER 

            if( @$cal_data[$k] == '' )
            {
                $cal_data[$k] = $row->client_name;                
            }
            else
            {
                $cal_data[$k] .= ','.$row->client_name;                
            }

        }     

        // LOOP THROUGH EACH DAY TO FIND THOSE WITH MORE THAN 5 EVENTS
        foreach($cal_data as $key=>$val){
            // COUNT THE NUMBER OF COMMAS THAT OCCUR IN STRING
            $count = strlen($val) - strlen(str_replace(',','',$val));
            if($count > 4){ // IF MORE THAN 4 COMMAS (> 5 EVENTS) THEN NO LINK... 
                $cal_data[$key] = '{day}<span class="date-data">'.$val.'</span>';   
            } else { // LINKED DAY 
                $cal_data[$key] = '<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bookingform" data="'.$year.'-'.$month.'-{day}">{day}</a><span class="date-data">'.$val.'</span>';               
            }
        }

        return $cal_data;
    }
```

**Note:** that I have changed two rows in the template: `{cal_cell_content}{content}{/cal_cell_content}` and `{cal_cell_content_today}<div class="highlight">{content}</div>{/cal_cell_content_today}`

You now only need to set `{content}` since `{day}` is specified inside the content also containing the html returned from the query.

**Update:** I have now tested the solution and it seems to work fine!

You have to manipulate or extend the Calendar library if you need a more flexible solution and if you don't want to mix template html in the content returned from your query.